# MongoDB - Return all regex matches from an Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongoDB document that contains a list of email address. I'd like to use a regEx expression to return an array of matching email address in the single document. I don't need to find all matches in the Collection. I'm assuming I need to use aggregation but I can't get it to work correctly. Any advice?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "621fbc842ff7d84973d537e7"
    },
    "name": "Test",
    "emailAddresses": ["email@email.com", "email2@email.com", "dave@test.com", "frank@email.com"],
    "_class": "com.email.models.Group"
}
```

Search for "ema", would return:

```
{
    "emailAddresses": ["email@email.com", "email2@email.com", "frank@email.com" ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
   $addFields: {
     emailAddresses: {
      $filter: {
       input: "$emailAddresses",
       cond: {
        "$regexMatch": {
          input: "$$this",
          regex: "ema"
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
 ])
```

Explained:

Define addFields aggregation stage with $filter to replace the original emailAddresses array , in the input for the filter provide the emailAddresses array and condition for the filter add regex expression by which the array elements will be filtered.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C03TjGpY9cD)